# Exporting pixel value of a dataset

Tags: google-earth-engine, java, pixel, list

I'm trying to export the value of a dataset for each pixel.
I made it this way :

```
var chloa_4kmOnly = chloa_4km.select("Chloa_OC3").clip(geometry)
print(chloa_4kmOnly)
var chloaFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(chloa_4kmOnly
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer : ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry : geometry, 
    crs : ModisProjection
  })
  .get('Chloa_OC3'))
  .map(function(chloa){
    return ee.Feature(null, {chloa_4kmOnly : chloa_4kmOnly})
  })
)
print(chloaFeatures.aggregate_array("chloa_4kmOnly"))
```

But instead of having a list of values like this
[image]

I got this

[image]

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the results of `reduceRegion()`. You probably wanted to do this:

```
return ee.Feature(null, {chloa_4kmOnly : chloa})
```

Comment: Thanks its working.